# css animation for text color and moving text, with jquery example

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to animate my text color, and have an > move about 15px to the right after the text on hover. I think this is possible with css, but not sure where to start.

```
$('#home_solutions_list li').mouseenter(function() {
  link = $(this).find('.home_view_products a');
  link.stop(true, true).animate({
   'color': '#636a6d'
  }, 'fast');
  link.find('span').animate({
   'padding-left': '20px'
   }, 'fast');
});
```

So the color should change (not working jsfiddle), and then the span element after should move to the right of the text. But ONLY the span element should move, currently as the text is centered, the link text is also moving. Can this just be done simply in css?

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/2278/

Answer (score 1):

Set this:

```
.home_view_products a span {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

And change your JS to this:

```
$('#home_solutions_list li').mouseenter(function() {
  link = $(this).find('.home_view_products a');
  link.stop(true, true).animate({
    'color': '#636a6d'
  }, 'fast');
  link.find('span').animate({
    'left': '20px',
  }, 'fast');
});
$('#home_solutions_list li').mouseleave(function() {
  link = $(this).find('.home_view_products a');
  link.stop(true, true).animate({
    'color': '#1a92d0'
  }, 'fast');
  link.find('span').animate({
    'left': '5px'
  }, 'fast');
});
```

However, I suggest creating a class for hover and offhover, and setting those classes with using CSS selectors rather than any JS. Just a small tip.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with pure CSS by adding a trigger on the angle bracket when the link is hovered over.

```
a:hover > .tag {
      color: orange;
      position: relative;
      left: 15px;
}
a > .tag {
      position: relative;
      left: 0
}
a > .tag, a:hover > .tag {
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
      transition: all 1s ease
}
```

The CSS `>` selector is used to select all matching children of a particular element; in this case, we are looking for all elements of class `tag` that are immediate descendants of anchor elements.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnequ7uq/

Comment: what about the entire a element changing color? rather than just the tag?

Comment: What do you want to change the color of?

Comment: the entire <a> element

Comment: then add a rule for a with the :hover pseudo-selector. e.g. `a:hover { color: orange; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to move the centered text, you have to make sure that the span element is out of the flow.
I would position it relative.
The animation with css is done with left:20px on hover:

```
.home_view_products a span {
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition:padding-left 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  transition:left 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

#home_solutions_list li:hover span {
  left:20px;
  color:#636a6d;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/1j7dzfda/3/